# Clang++: Use AddressSanitizer for small portion of library

Tags: clang++, address-sanitizer

I am working on a quite large code base and some snippets I added are causing weird memory behaviour so I considered using the `-fsanitize=address` option for `clang++`.

However it seems I cannot make it compile the whole library, because of a whole bunch of errors caused by the linker.

I am not really aware of the inner workings of the AddressSanitizer, but is it generally possible to *apply* it only to a small portion of a library's code base (let's say to a single header) and if so how?

Comment: Are you compiling a shared library or executable? Details of the answer depend on that.

Comment: I am compiling an executable

Comment: Do you pass `-fsanitize=address` in `LDFLAGS`? What are the linker errors?